# identifer "Month" is undefined

Tags: c++

I'm trying to initialize a Date object using one of the enumerator Month variables, but the compiler is giving the error

> identifier "Month" is undefined

Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Year {
    static const int max = 1800;
    static const int min = 2200;
public:
    class Invalid {} ;
    Year(int x) : y(x){ if ( x < min || x >= max ) throw Invalid(); }
    int year() { return y; }
private:
    int y;
};


class Date {
private:
    Year y;
    Month m;  // ERROR HERE
    int d;
public:
    Date( Month m, int d, Year y) // ERROR HERE AT Mont m
        :m(m), d(d), y(y) {}
    void add_day(int n);
    int month() {return m; }
    int day() { return d; }
    Year year() { return y; }
    enum Month { jan =1, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec };
};    

Date today(Date::sep, 24, Year(1989));

void main() {
    cout << today.day() << endl << today.month() << endl << today.year() << endl;
}
```

Comment: u r using `Month` enum before declaring it.

Comment: Where's Month declaration? I can see it after its use, not before...

Comment: @Rakibul Thanks, for some reason I thought it didn't matter what order you put things in in a class.

Comment: The compiler also gave the exact line and column where `Month` was found. Why didn't you include that? (Not that it mattered, we lot are good at crystal ball reading. ;-) ) As for sequence mattering... C/C++ were designed in a way that allows *single-pass* compilation. This requires "declaration before use", inside of classes as well as outside.

Comment: @Devsolar: as Matt McNabb mentions in his answer, inline member function bodies can use class members that haven't been declared yet. In fact `Year::year()` in the example does exactly that. So I can understand that this might be a confusing detail.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Gee... yes, I never actually thought about that. :-D

Answer (score 1):

You have to have `enum Month` before you can go `Month m;`.  It doesn't work quite like inline function bodies which do have access to other variables of the class that haven't been defined yet.

One option is just to move the whole definition up to before the private variables (or put the private variables at the end).

In C++11 you can also do:

```
class Date
{
    enum Month : int;    // forward-declaration; requires type spec
...
    enum Month : int { jan = 1, .....
};
```

Note that your `cout` line in `main` also needs work. `today.year()` cannot be sent to `cout` as it stands.

One options is to change it to `today.year().year()`. This is ungainly; I'd suggest that you change within `class Year` the function `int year()` to have a better name, e.g. `year_as_int() const`.

Also you can define a stream insertion operator (this is at file scope, not inside the class definition):

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Year const &y)
{
    return os << y.year_as_int();
}
```

Also, all member functions which do not modify the member variables should have a `const` qualifier.  Then they can be called from objects you only have a const reference to, as in my example here.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix it is to shift the definition of the `enum Month` to a location before the first usage:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Year {
    static const int max = 2200;
    static const int min = 1800;
public:
    class Invalid {} ;
    Year(int x) :
            y(x)
    {
        if ( x < min || x >= max ) throw Invalid();
    }
    int year() { return y; }
private:
    int y;
};


class Date {
public:
    enum Month { jan =1, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec };   
private:
    Year y;
    Month m;  // ERROR HERE
    int d;
public:
    Date( Month m, int d, Year y) // ERROR HERE AT Mont m
        :m(m), d(d), y(y) {}
    void add_day(int n);
    int month() {return m; }
    int day() { return d; }
    Year year() { return y; }
};    


int main() {
    Date today(Date::sep, 24, Year(1989));

    cout << today.day() << endl << today.month() << endl << today.year().year() << endl;
} 


/*
    Local Variables:
    compile-command: "g++ -g test.cc"
    End:
 */
```

Note, that with your construction you need today.year().year() in the output or define `<<` for `Year`. Furthermore, in `Year` the values for `min` and `max` were swapped.